# Convolution is linear and continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $1\le p,q,r\le \infty,\   \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1+\frac{1}{r},\  g\in L^q , f \in L^p $.

I want to prove $T_g:f\rightarrow f\star g $ is linear and continuous from $L^p$ to $L^r$.

$T_g$ is linear if $T_g(\alpha f_1+\beta f_2)=\alpha T_g( f_1)+\beta T_g(f_2)$?

For linearity: $T_g(\alpha f_1+\beta f_2)=\int_{\Omega} (\alpha f_1+\beta f_2)(x-y)g(y) dy=\int_{\Omega}\alpha f_1(x-y) g(y) dy+\int_{\Omega}\beta f_2(x-y) g(y) dy=\alpha T_gf_1+\beta T_gf_2$

But for the continuity?

Comment: @Surb He's right. See Young's inequality.

Comment: Yes, you get continuity immediately from Young 's inequality. The norm of the operator is at most $\|g\|$

Comment: What is your question exactly? Yes you can use Young's inequality, if it is a known result to you.

Comment: if the convolution operator is linear and continuous

Comment: Did you mean for $g$ to be in $L^q$?

Comment: Yes.The linearity is right?